# Create PHP+HTML page to start process

Tags: php, python, html, irc

I've got a file, tenoticebot.py, that I would like to be able to start and stop from a PHP page. Is this possible? I think the page would need to start the script from a user's account, launch it into the background (screen), get and keep the process ID, and then be able to kill that process. Is this possible and may I have the code? Or can you suggest a simpler version and the code for that?
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'from a user's account'?

Comment: @maxhud probably that, when you start a process, it has to belong to some local user on the machine (server). Better a user account than root or the webservers'.

Comment: @maxhud Niko would be correct.

Comment: The best way which I can think of doing this is to create a start/stop shell script and call that from PHP using exec()